# Variable captured by closure before being initialized

Tags: swift, uitableview, closures

I'm trying to store the number of results from a query into an integer so that I can use it to determine the number of rows in a table. However, I'm getting the following error: `Variable 'numberOfGames' captured by a closure before being initialized'` on the line `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{`.

I also get another error `Variable 'numberOfGames' used before being initialized` on the line `return numberOfGames`.

Here's the function that contains the two errors:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        var user: PFUser!

        var numberOfGames: Int

        //...query code....removed to make it easier to read

        var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, userQuery2, currentUserQuery, currentUserQuery2])
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            }

            if error == nil{

                if results != nil{
                    println(results)
                    numberOfGames = results!.count as Int
                }
            }
        }
        return numberOfGames
    }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable before use it inside a closure:

[As per apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest
>   of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the
>   closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other
>   property values from within your closure, even if those properties
>   have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property,
>   or call any of the instance’s methods.

The command `var numberOfGames: Int` just declare it to initialize you can use `var numberOfGames = Int()` or `var numberOfGames:Int = 0`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        var user: PFUser!
        var numberOfGames:Int = 0
        var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, userQuery2, currentUserQuery, currentUserQuery2])
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            }
            if error == nil{
                if results != nil{
                    println(results)
                    numberOfGames = results!.count as Int
                }
            }
        }
        return numberOfGames
    }
```

Comment: *facepalm ... I need to learn the difference between declare and initializing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Anton, Wouldn't the alternative be to let the program intermittently crash at runtime without prior warning, via attempting to access a memory address without a value?

Comment: Somehow it was all working elegantly and without million pitfalls in objc day and age predating the design-by-committee of swift