# invalid initializer call with same type 'XXXX' as parameter

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum Seat: String{
    case middle
    case aisle
    case window
    case undefined
}

let s : Seat = Seat(rawValue: Seat.middle)
```

doing such gives me

> error: invalid initializer call with same type 'Seat' as parameter

It seems like a simple error. I searched online but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite obvious.

The `rawValue` parameter expects a `String`. But you're giving it the enum type itself.

You should either do:

```
let s: Seat = .middle
let s = Seat(rawValue: "middle") ?? .undefined
let s = Seat(rawValue: "middle")! // Perhaps this is better, per Alexander's comment
```

or just for demonstration purposes:

```
let s = Seat(rawValue: Seat.middle.rawValue) ?? .undefined
```

<sub>I created this error by changing the type of my `s` property from `String` to `Seat`. But since the change was made at a file different from the file where the enum was defined...I got confused.</sub>

Comment: To whom you are addressing in this answer??

Comment: Ya akh al arab, Salam :D! To the community. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Yallah tamam ya habibi!

Comment: `let s : Seat = .middle`

Comment: I think it's better to force unwrap `Seat(rawValue: Seat.middle.rawValue)` than to default to `.undefined`. If the initializer returns `nil`, then Swift's broken and you should probably know about it.

Comment: @Alexander for once I saw a good use case for force unwrapping. Something that is not much opinionated...

Comment: @Honey Here is [another example](https://repl.it/repls/BareSupportiveAddons) where `!` is pretty much forced.

Comment: @Alexander clever. I don't get it though. To understand I removed the forced unwrapping and got this error: **captured by a closure before being initialized**. Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905038/variable-captured-by-closure-before-being-initialized). Not sure if that applies to this situation. Can you shed some light on this. Particularly, can you keep the structure of your code, but still write it *without* force unwrapping?

Comment: @Honey Swift requires that all code in a closure be valid *at the time the closure is defined*, and *not* when the closure is called. Thus, when the compiler is parsing through the middle of the closure, `factorial` doesn't yet have a value. The compiler doesn't know that it's *about* to have a value *very soon*, so it's ill formed in its current state.

Comment: @Honey You can use something called a Y combinator to get around this, but it's pretty tricky. I'm learning it myself, right now.

Comment: @Alexander _Thus, when the compiler is parsing through the middle of the closure, factorial doesn't yet have a value_ I don't get this part. Nor I understand how force unwrapping it would help. I totally get it that all values must be initializable either through their default values (which can also be `nil` though optionals) or the `init` method. Still don't get this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170639/discussion-between-alexander-and-honey).