# Swift error when assigning to struct inside firebase query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to query to my Firestore database and assign the values to my user struct, but I am getting error:

> Variable 'self.firstName' captured by a closure before being initialized

How do I work around this?

```
let uid: Int
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var age: Int
var funds: Double

init(uid: Int) {
    self.uid = uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").whereField(K.User.uid, isEqualTo: uid)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
            } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count != 1 {
                print("More than 1 user?")
            } else {
                if let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first {
                    let data = document.data()
                    if let firstName = data[K.User.firstName] as? String, let lastName = data[K.User.lastName] as? String, let age = data[K.User.age] as? Int, let funds = data[K.User.funds] as? Double {

                        self.firstName = firstName
                        self.lastName = lastName
                        self.age = age
                        self.funds = funds

                    } else {
                        print("Error assigning variables")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you may need to assign a value to the vars you have, for example,  `var firstName: String = ""` etc...
before you use them in your code, such as `self.firstName = firstName`. You could also move the code to a separate function, but still declare those vars with an initail value in `init()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable captured by closure before being initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905038/variable-captured-by-closure-before-being-initialized)

Comment: I tried doing that but then get the error: "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter"

Comment: this one is a bad approach btw

Comment: Note, you should not do this kind of asynchronous work inside a `User` struct.
 Re-structure your code with,
 for example, a `struct User {...}`, and a `ObservableObject` class
 with a `@Published var user:...`, to do the db access and fetching.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Could you provide me a link to guide or best practices for the idea you are listing for backend structure I am new to swift.

Comment: I would absolutely avoid performing network ops in a model's initializer. The model (the structure) should be completely separated from the task of querying the database. Query the database, parse the documents, and then initialize the structure using the document's data.

Comment: @fakegirlfriends could you provide a guide or tutorial for best practice backend implementation like your describing for UIKit?

Comment: I would just Google search "Firestore iOS tutorials" and read as many as you can until you're comfortable with it. Firebase also has a git repo with sample iOS apps, specifically for Firestore (https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-ios/tree/master/FriendlyEats). But maybe you can forget Firestore for a moment and just Google search "iOS MVC tutorial" or "iOS MVVM tutorial". MVC is a simpler paradigm, the one that iOS and UIKit were originally built on. MVVM is all the rage now but MVC is solid and works very well. Learn them both.

Comment: The lesson you must ultimately learn is that every object should have its own well-defined role. The model (i.e. a structure named `Restaurant` in a restaurant app) has the role of representing a restaurant, and nothing more. You give its properties values and it holds them for you. The role of fetching restaurant data from a database should be given to another object, perhaps a data manager. The data manager would download this data and instantiate restaurant models and put them into an array. Then another object, like a view model, would render that array onto the screen. This is MVC/MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing.

The error can be fixed by defining your vars differently. Instead of

```
var firstName: String
```

change it to

```
var firstName = ""
```

so they will init with a default empty string.

But, *how* it's being done may (will) become problematic.

The first thing is - is generally best practice to store users in a users collection with the users uid as the documentId. That eliminates all of that code and becomes much more lightweight.

```
func loadUser() {
    myFirebase.collection("users").document("uid_0").getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard let document = documentSnapshot else { return }
        let myUser = User(withDoc: document)
        //do something with myUser - perhaps return it in a completionHandler
    }
}
```

also, it's not necessary to store loading code like that in every user struct. So a function somewhere in your main class would work and the user class becomes simpler

```
class User {
    var firstName = ""
    
    convenience init(withDoc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.firstName = withDoc["name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

So that's the basics for clarity. I now suggest looking at using Codable to populate your objects and here's super-article that covers that topic

[Mapping Firestore Data in Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)